# Crystal Report 2008's HTML Preview

Tags: html, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Whenever I tried to see the `HTML Preview` in Crystal Report 2008 (old, I know), there's an error message saying :

```
Failed to connect to server "localhost".
Error returned from Windows Sockets API: 0.
Please check the name of the RAS Server.
```

Just `Preview` works fine.